# How to update the order of multiple items via REST API?

Tags: rest, httprequest

I'm working on a **REST API for a list of navigation menu items**, pretty much for learning purposes. Until this point everything in the API was pretty straightforward because I only had to modify single items via the classic `/collection/{id}` stuff.

But now **I want to change the order of the list items stored in the `order` field** of my database and of course **I don't want to do one request for each menu item.**

So what would be an appropriate way / a common **best practice of doing this?**

I could imagine sending a `PUT` request to `/collection` with the id-order key-value pairs in the sent data but Laravel (which I use to build the API) does not allow this. I certainly could play around that restriction but I guess there are sensible reasons that this is not allowed.

Another idea would be to send a `PUT` request to `/collection/{ids}` with a comma-separated list of IDs but for that I also would have to send a key-value list of the IDs and their order value which seems pretty redundant and due to that also a little dirty.

So what would actually be the best approach?

Comment: Use PATCH to update partial fields in records and send an array of requests then just iterate through them in laravel and update the records accordingly

Comment: PATCH sounds actually pretty useful, I seem to have overseen that method. But still that doesn't really solve my problem - or what do you mean by an "array of requests"?

Comment: Are you using a form or AJAX elements?

Comment: I'm exclusively using AJAX.

Comment: Ok please post your Ajax code ill give you my opinion

Comment: I don't have any, this is a purely conceptional question how the request itself should be structured to match good practice, maybe there are some common patterns because I'm certainly not the first one stepping over this issue.

Comment: So tell me how would you handle reordering 1 record?

Comment: As described above I'd probably use a PUT (or now better: PATCH) request to url/items/id with a data object providing the order value like { order: *integer* }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you define a new route with a resource path: /collection/reorder.

This allows to send it using the method `POST` the list of elements with their new positions. The content will look like something like that:

```
{
    "element1": 4,
    "element2": 1,
    (...)
}
```

"element1" is the identifier of an element and the corresponding value, its new order.

You can notice that the format of data you need to send to this method can be depend on the tool you use in the UI to reorder the list (for example, for drag'n drop).

Hope it helps.
Thierry

Comment: That sounds actually useful. I wasn't sure if it's appropriate to define a new route for something that's not actually a model or collection. Thanks!

Comment: I commonly use the method POST of the resource /collection/ to add an element to the collection. Perhaps this link can help you: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.